# How do I implementing statistical hypothesis testing with python?

Tags: python

If I have a steady mean of 45 for long period, a standard deviation of 11 and a sample of size of 80 with mean of 43, how can I run test a against 0.05 and 0.1 level of significance using python?

I am doing statistics hypothesis testing

> Hypothesis testing is a critical tool in inferential statistics for determining what the value of a population parameter could be.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a student's t-test, but before we get to that, you'll have to calculate standard error for your samples.

Here's code to calculate standard error. `std1` and `std2` represent standard deviation for each sample, which you already have.

```
# calculate standard errors
# calculate standard errors
n1, n2 = len(data1), len(data2)
se1, se2 = std1/sqrt(n1), std2/sqrt(n2)
```

Once you've calculated stand error, you can then calculate the results of your t-test using this code:

```
# function for calculating the t-test for two independent samples
def independent_ttest(data1, data2, alpha):
    # calculate means
    mean1, mean2 = mean(data1), mean(data2)
    # calculate standard errors
    se1, se2 = sem(data1), sem(data2)
    # standard error on the difference between the samples
    sed = sqrt(se1**2.0 + se2**2.0)
    # calculate the t statistic
    t_stat = (mean1 - mean2) / sed
    # degrees of freedom
    df = len(data1) + len(data2) - 2
    # calculate the critical value
    cv = t.ppf(1.0 - alpha, df)
    # calculate the p-value
    p = (1.0 - t.cdf(abs(t_stat), df)) * 2.0
    # return everything
    return t_stat, df, cv, p
```